# use curl to upload in memory csv file

Tags: csv, curl, post

I am currently using Python perform a POST to a desired url and upload an in memory csv file:

Python code:

```
csv_content = 'some,fake,single,row,csv\r\n'
requests.post(
    'http://some.location.com',
    files={'form_field_name': ('file_name.csv', csv_content, 'text/csv')},
    # implicit "multipart/form-data" content-type header
)
```

The Python code works well, but I really want to use `curl` to perform the action.

What I have: (I know it is missing a lot, I tried variations of

```
curl -X POST http://some.location.com -H "Content-Type: text/csv"
```

1. I am not sure the header is good
2. Not sure how to specify the data, as `-d` would not be enough - I want to add a file name as well

Answer (score 1):

How about this answer? There are several solutions for your situation, so please think of this as one of them.

When your python script is run, `"form_field_name": "some,fake,single,row,csv\r\n"` is sent as `files`. `file_name.csv` is used as the filename. In this case, the request body is as follows.

#### Request body:

```
--boundaryboundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_field_name"; filename="file_name.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

some,fake,single,row,csv

--boundaryboundary--
```

#### Sample curl:

When above request body is used, the sample curl is as follows.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundaryboundary" \
  -d $'--boundaryboundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="form_field_name"; filename="file_name.csv"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n\r\nsome,fake,single,row,csv\r\n\r\n--boundaryboundary--' \
  "http://some.location.com"
```

- `Content-Type` of the header uses `multipart/form-data; boundary=boundaryboundary`.
- The request body is directly used.
- The filename is given as `file_name.csv`.
- Each line break was replaced to `\r\n`.

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: thank you for your time :)
I tried using the curl you posted, used my real data, but it does not succeed

Comment: @camelBack Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About ``it does not succeed``, can I ask you about the detail information and can you confirm your python script again? Because my sample curl is the same request body with your python script. I would like to confirm your situation and modify it.